# How can i change credentials for twitter and Facebook using share kit

Tags: objective-c, credentials, sharekit

I use sharekit(http://getsharekit.com/) and i managed to share informations to twitter, my problem is that when the user give his credentials i can't change them later, is there a way for the user to delete his credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using  `[SHKTwitter logout];`

Comment: when and where?? do i have to make a button somewhere?

Comment: Yes, add a button like "logout" and assign this command to it. Redirect user to a homepage or an authentication screen if users in this app are authenticated via Twitter or show "Twitter - not linked" somewhere in your app. I suppose you really should be a little bit more concerned about your app design if you are actually developing an app and not testing sharekit capabilities.